# PowerShell: Can't get process exit code

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to start a process with the following piece of code

```
$temFi = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$myPro = Start-Process myExe.exe -ArgumentList ("a1","a2") -RedirectStandardOutput $temFi -PassThru -NoNewWindow
if( $myPro -ne $null) 
        {if( -NOT $myPro.HasExited) 
            {$myPro.WaitForExit() }  
        }
Write-Host $myPro.ExitCode
```

However, by the time I get to the ExitCode, it is null, eventhought $myPro.HasExited = True

Also, I see in the temporary file that the process failed and returned non-zero. But, if I check $lastExitCode after the code above, it is 0

What am I missing ? I'm working with PS v3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly a typo, you are missing a closing bracket '}'

Comment: Indeed a typo. I just fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  on Process HasExited,

> When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers, it is possible that output 
>   processing will not have completed when HasExited returns true.

So, I guess that is what the problem is here..